# MATLAB: print set of streamlines to file

Tags: matlab, file, output

I am plotting streamlines over a non uniform grid of a 2D vector field:

```
streamlines=stream2(X,Y,U,V,startx,starty)
```

then I plot them with:

```
streamline(streamlines)
```

Now, I would like to dump them to an ASCII file. 
Is it possible? Any clue?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`dlmwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html):

```
dlmwrite('streamlinesfilename',streamlines);
```

The default delimiter is set to `,` so be sure to specify the `delimiter`
 option if you need a different one:

```
dlmwrite('streamlinesfilename',streamlines,'delimiter',';');
```